# AnyLogic Discrete Event Model Unique Identifier

Tags: events, unique, anylogic

I am building a discrete event model with AnyLogic.  I would like to assign unique ID to each agent which comes into the process.  I included a variable, ID and another variable, clientID. When the entity gets "this.clientID = ID++;" on at exit.  I noticed that there are multiple agents which are getting the exactly the same ID.  Are there any ways to assign unique ID to each agent as they are entering a system?

Answer (score 1):

Each agent has unique id, it is generated internally, and may be returned with `getId()` function.

Unique ID may be generated as you describe as well. Then, you should have custom agent type with `clientID` variable at canvas. `Source` block should create new agents of this type. `Main` should have at canvas a variable called `ID`. On At Exit action code of `Source` block should be: `agent.clientID = ID++;`

BTW, `getIndex()` call is not safe, since it returns agent index within population. If population size changes, agent index within population may change as well. `getIndex()` may return the same index for different agents in case if they are in different population. At last, `getIndex()` always returns `-1` for standalone agents.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how agent-based works:

if the agent holds the variable "ID", then each agent has its own value for "ID". Hence they all get the same value when each of them individually executes the "ID++" code.

Each agent already has a unique ID assigned by AnyLogic upon its creation. You can retrieve it using "myAgent.getIndex()".

hope this helps